# What will happen if MySQL cannot write to InnoDB log?

Tags: mysql, innodb

What happens to MySQL if the partition that contains InnoDB's log files (innodb_log_group_home_dir) becomes full, read-only or otherwise unwritable?

If this did happen, what recovery process would be required? Could I use a slave to aid recovery of the master?

Comment: What's the basis of your question?

Comment: Just curious. If something happens to the `data_dir` disk/array, the data is gone so recovery from slave or backup is necessary. What if something happens to `innodb_log_group_home_dir`?

Answer (score 0):

Got a response on the MySQL InnoDB Forum. I that swear my question sounded less dumb when I posted it.

> InnoDB cannot operate without the
>   iblog files. They are pre-allocated,
>   so "out of space" is not a failure
>   mode, unwritable is.
>
> The slave's iblog, binlog, relaylog,
>   general log, etc, are all useless by
>   themselves.
>
> You should plan on stopping the slave,
>   copying all the files over, etc, to
>   rebuild the Master.